# Auto-remount CIFS share

Tags: automounting, cifs

I have a CIFS mount in fstab which works fine, except when something goes wrong with the network or the remote server and it doesn't recover. I want the share to auto-remount in the event of failure, but from what I've read this isn't supported via fstab.

What I've done for now is move it to an autofs mount, which to be fair works well, but I've always found autofs mounts a bit laggy vs fstab (just my perception visually on the command line). Does anyone have any experience of another solution for this?

Answer (score 3):

As far as remounting the mounts present in your `/etc/fstab`, you can use this method to force a remount:

```
$ sudo mount -a -t cifs
```

Per `man mount`:

```
   -t, --types vfstype
   [...]

   More than one type may be specified in a comma  separated  list.
   The  list of filesystem types can be prefixed with no to specify
   the filesystem types on which no action should be taken.   (This
   can be meaningful with the -a option.) For example, the command:

            mount -a -t nomsdos,ext
```

You could then put a check in a shell script which would force the `mount -a -t cifs` command to run based on either a scheduled time or come up with a check using `inotify` or something else that would verify the status of the mounts, and if it detects that they've failed, run the `mount ..` command I provided above.

Answer (score 0):

## Auto-mounting (and remounting) with `systemd`

For the purposes of this example let's say our share is "**Loads o' Big-Storage**"

(because it works well to illustrate `systemd` file path and unit file escaping, which most tutorials don't cover)

1. Create your mount point:

   ```bash
   sudo mkdir -p "/mnt/Loads o' Big-Storage"
   sudo chown -R "$(whoami)":"$(whoami)" "/mnt/Loads o' Big-Storage"
   ```
2. Use `systemd-escape --path` to create a `.mount` filename:

   ```bash
   my_systemd_mountfile="$(
       systemd-escape --path "/mnt/Loads o' Big-Storage"
   )"
   echo "${my_systemd_mountfile}"
   ```

   ```
   mnt-Loads\x20o\x27\x20Big\x2dStorage
   ```
3. Create that file in `/etc/system/system/` with *literal* file path contents (no escapes)

   ```bash
   sudo vim "/etc/system/system/${my_systemd_mountfile}.mount"
   ```

   ```ini
   [Unit]
   Description=My CIFs Media Mounter
   Requires=network-online.target
   After=network-online.service

   [Mount]
   What=//192.168.2.200/Loads o' Big-Storage
   Where=/mnt/Loads o' Big-Storage
   Options=username=foo-user,password=foo-secret
   Type=cifs

   [Install]
   WantedBy=multi-user.target
   EOF
   ```
4. Create the corresponding `.automount` file:

   ```bash
   sudo vim "/etc/system/system/${my_systemd_mountfile}.automount"
   ```

   ```ini
   [Unit]
   Description=My CIFs Media Automounter

   [Automount]
   Where=/mnt/Loads o' Big-Storage

   [Install]
   WantedBy=multi-user.target
   ```
5. Load and enable the service:

   ```bash
   sudo systemctl daemon-reload
   sudo systemctl enable "${my_systemd_mountfile}".automount
   sudo systemctl start "${my_systemd_mountfile}".automount
   ```

## Troubleshooting

If you have troubles, `journalctl` will have better log info than self-recommended `systemd status`:

```bash
sudo journalctl -xe "${my_systemd_mountfile}".mount
```